# how to extract json like this in c#

Tags: c#

```
{
  "ErrorCode": "ESB-14-021",
  "ErrorMessage": {
    "Indonesian": "API Key Tidak Valid",
    "English": "API Key Invalid"
  }
}
```

model and exctracting code

Comment: This might come in handy to get you started: https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that problem is that you have "dynamic" properties in the json object stored in `ErrorMessage` property - you can use the approach with dictionaries to represent this in C# class, which is supported by at least two of the main JSON serializers in .NET nowadays - `System.Text.Json` and `Newtonsoft`. For example using the former one (and C# 11 raw string literals):

```cs
var json = """
{
  "ErrorCode": "ESB-14-021",
  "ErrorMessage": {
    "Indonesian": "API Key Tidak Valid",
    "English": "API Key Invalid"
  }
}
""";
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ErrorResponse>(json);

Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorCode); // ESB-14-021
Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorMessage["Indonesian"]); // API Key Tidak Valid

public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string ErrorCode {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> ErrorMessage {get;set;}
}
```

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSAsA3OlrkgHQAqApgB7DkBSAzgPZTFolICcAFACJAPBuAQfYEBKTugBuAQzDYAVmyjYAvNgFb0Ab3TZNAUTBhWYAMKsAJtQEgjAZQBCAWgIvMyAQBp9Rk2YAstTMzLIA5rb2emgGBgIAklBW7CEAlrJQdpoAggAKCdgA0tQAntiUaVayANbYAGqyADZVPn7xhlDhLcwAFtkC+YUl5UlyLVYCfgC+6LNoWgKccgpgIRBNwOrYLOwO1GAZLQBeB+QAIiEHR2mnADzGpmAASiEADuzM1AB8fMrsknQ3H4a2YGwYjzMlhsgIwvD4oPB5EhYGCoQi1AA2olkqlmBksgBdWEkADMuAQ2BRr2YHygX107Vw5LwOBR0Oo2B0kWAhC+vPmcWZ2HOaQAxsA0ux5KU7qzvGRMN8qQFUSEwpEuTy+dQBXMgA)

Answer (score -1):

```
ErrorResponse response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ErrorResponse>(json);


public class ErrorResponse
{
public string ErrorCode {get;set;}
public Message ErrorMessage {get;set;}
}
public class Message
{
public string Indonesian {get;set;}
public string English {get;set;}
}
```